# Ajax in cakephp not rendering page as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm new to ajax/javascript/jquery and am trying to render a page onto a a page that includes my form. I am getting it to render but when it does it goes to my form page, except it actually loads the page, ignores the layout and removes my form.

Here is my controller code:

```
<?php
class PlayersController extends AppController{
       public $components = array('RequestHandler');
       public function listall() {
          $this->set ( 'players', $this->Player->find ( 'all' ) );
       }

       public function index() {
          if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
               $this->Player->create();
                  if ($this->Player->save ( $this->request->data )){    
                       $this->set ( 'players', $this->Player->find ( 'all' ));
                       $this->render('listall', 'ajax');        
                   }
            }
      }
  }?>
```

Here is my view for the form:

```
    <?php 
       echo $this->Form->create();
       echo $this->Form->input('name',array('id' => 'name')); 
       echo $this->Js->submit('Save', array(
        'before' => $this->Js->get('#inprogress')->effect('fadeIn'),
        'success' => $this->Js->get('#inprogress')->effect('fadeOut'),
        'update' => '#success'

        ));     
       echo $this->Form->submit('normal submit');
       echo $this->Form->end();
?>
        <div id="inprogress" style="display: none;background-color: 
                 lightblue">Saving in progress...</div>
```

Here is my view to be rendered:

```
      <p style="background-color: lightblue">Players</p>
       <table>
       <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
       </>tr
               <?php foreach ($players as $players): ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td><?php echo h($players['Player']['name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                 </tr> 
                     <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
```

And this is what I have in my layout to bring in the jquery:

```
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-2.1.0.min');
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this-Js->writeBuffer(array('cache' => TRUE));
```

I've been trying to figure out how to actually render the the view listall inside the view index without actually reloading page. At a loss right now.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand what actually you are doing with the information you provided. Well try this-

**in you controller**

```
<?php
class PlayersController extends AppController{
       public $components = array('RequestHandler');
       public function listall() {
          $this->layout = 'ajax';
          $this->set ( 'players', $this->Player->find ( 'all' ) );
       }

       public function index() {
          if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
               $this->Player->create();
                  if ($this->Player->save ( $this->request->data )){    
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Congrats');       
                   }
            }
      }
  }?>
```

Comment: Thanks, what this does though is render the index view so I end up with two forms.

What I am trying to do: I have a list of all players (listall) now on my form I want to add a player to the list and then render the list of all the players on the index.

So basically render the listall view on to the index view when I use the js save instead of the submit.